# Enable JPA 2nd level cache in Spring Data JPA repository

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I try to enable JPA 2nd level cache for Spring Data JPA. I enabled cache in persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="ds-default">
    <jta-data-source>SAMPLE_DATASOURCE</jta-data-source>
    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

In my repository I provided query hints for the cache as well:

```
public interface SampleRepository extends JpaRepository<SampleEntity, String> {

    @Override
    @QueryHints(value = {
            @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true")
    })
    List<SampleEntity> findAll();
}
```

I expect that the result of findAll query should be cached and that I should see only one select query in the logs. However, I see it more than once which leads me to the conclusion that cache is not configured correctly. What am I missing?

I do not want to use the Spring Cache mechanism (I do not use Spring Boot etc.).

Comment: If you configure a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory` in java add the properties in java code instead of in the `persistence.xml`.

Comment: I do not create EntityManagerFactory by my own (I inject EntityManager via @PersistenceContext)

Comment: Please read my comment. From your question you aren't using Spring Boot so you have something in your configuration to configure the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory` which in turn creates the `EntityManagerFactory`.

Comment: It is provided by the Application Server (JBoss or WebSphere).

Comment: You must have something in your Spring configuration that adds the bean else it won't work. Or you aren't using Spring and are using Spring Data JPA in a JEE environment (which is possible but makes a huge difference in answering the question!). Also make sure that your entities are cacheable (i.e. have the `@Cacheable` annotation, else it won't cache either.

Comment: I am using the second option means CDI + Spring Data JPA (in JEE environment).

Comment: Then please change your question and tags, as it now looks like you are using the most common Spring + Spring Data JPA setup. The latter is quite different from what you are using and will impact the answering (I was answering from the latter case, not helping you nor me). And as mentioned in my previous comment make sure your entities are `@Cacheable` as well else it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some steps to check and follow and a sample project in github:

1. Check in persistence.xml

   ```
   <persistence-unit name="testPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
   ...
           <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
          <properties>
   ...
           <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
           <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
           <property name="hibernate.cache.region_prefix" value="hibernate.test"/><!-- Optional -->
            <!-- Use Infinispan second level cache provider -->
           <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.infinispan.hibernate.cache.v53.InfinispanRegionFactory"/>

               <!-- Optional: Initialize a caches (for standalone mode / test purpouse) -->
               <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.cfg"
                         value="META-INF/infinispan-configs-local.xml"/> 
   ...
          </properties>
   </persistence>
   ```

PS: "org.infinispan.hibernate.cache.v53.InfinispanRegionFactory" package depends on your maven dependencies and Hibernate version.

2. If you want to use JCache interceptors. Add to beans.xml:

   ```
   <interceptors>
       <class>org.infinispan.jcache.annotation.InjectedCacheResultInterceptor</class>
       <class>org.infinispan.jcache.annotation.InjectedCachePutInterceptor</class>
       <class>org.infinispan.jcache.annotation.InjectedCacheRemoveEntryInterceptor</class>
       <class>org.infinispan.jcache.annotation.InjectedCacheRemoveAllInterceptor</class>
   </interceptors>
   ```

PS. Take in mind, that Infinispan have a variant without "Injected" in the name of the Interceptors for environments where the cache manager is not injected in a managed environment.

3. Check that your cache is configured (in your application server) or your cdi producer. Eg.

   ```
   @ApplicationScoped
   public class CacheConfigProducer {
   @Produces
   public Configuration defaultCacheConfiguration() {
   return new ConfigurationBuilder().simpleCache(false).customInterceptors().addInterceptor()
       .interceptor(new TestInfinispanCacheInterceptor()).position(Position.FIRST).expiration().lifespan(60000l)
       .build();
   }
   }
   ```
4. Add to your repository your hints like you are adding:

   ```
   @Eager public interface CacheableReadWriteRepository extends ReadWriteRepository<CacheableEntity, Integer>{

       @QueryHints(value = { @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.jpa.QueryHints.HINT_CACHEABLE, value = "true")})
       List<CacheableEntity> findByValue(Integer value);
   }
   ```
5. Take care to add @Cacheable to your entity

You have this project with Spring Data JPA and CDI integration ([spring-data-jpa with cdi](https://github.com/arielcarrera/cdi-spring-data-jpa-test)). It has tests with JCache, Hibernate 2nd level cache and query cache.

I hope it helps.